# Splitting a repository with the possibility to later pull changes

Tags: git, bitbucket

I have a repository in which I have boilerplate code for new projects.
I now have 2 projects for 2 different clients.  The projects have some resemblances.
Ideally if I were to add a new feature for project X that I think could be useful for the other project I want to add this non-specific code to the boilerplate and pull it into the repo's of the individual projects.  I something like this possible?
I don't want to work with branches in the same repository since both projects will be installed on the servers of the clients with capistrano (so they can pull changes when doing a deploy).  And I don't want client X to be able to see code of the other client.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the built-in [subtrees](https://lostechies.com/johnteague/2014/04/04/using-git-subtrees-to-split-a-repository/) (or their sometimes criticized alternative, also built-in, called [submodules](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules)).

And take a look at the [git-subrepo](https://github.com/ingydotnet/git-subrepo) project.

All those options allow you to have nested repositories. In your case, the boilerplate repository would be nested inside the clients' repositories. This would allow them to pull from the boilerplate repository without needing to share their core code with each other.